# How to use controller in vuejs2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

Hi I start using vuejs2 with project based on laravel backend
in my vuejs2, I did this code in the file `routes.js`

```
export default new VueRouter({
  routes: [{
      path: '/test',
      component: Test
    },
    {
      path: '/settings',
      component: Settings
    },
    // users
    {
      path: '/users/create',
      component: Create
    },
    // end users
  ],
});
```

Now in the line `{ path: '/users/create', component: Create}`, I'm wondering how could I go to controller first and the controller redirect me to the  component 
like in laravel first think I write in route.php and calling a function in the controller and the controller redirect me to the view vile 
what I found that's from the route I go to the component 
but I need to do things before redirecting me to the component 
thanks a lot.

Comment: You mean before finishing your request you want to perform some checks ?

Comment: yes some checks

Comment: You can use the global route guard `beforeEach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

. There is a guard available with VueRouter to perform checks. It is called BeforeEach(). What this will do is before resolving the next request in the pipeline it will check for the conditions to be satisfied.

```
const router = new VueRouter({ ... })

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if(some_condition){
      next();
  } else if(some_error){
       next('/'); //rerouting
  }
})
```

You can check this documentation : https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards

Here you can push the route you want to include in the pipeline using next() and 
change it according to your conditions.